# Missing Separator Make Error

Tags: makefile

```
$(foreach name, $(patsubst lib%.a,%,$(LIBS)), \
          $(eval lib$(name).a : lib$(name).a($$($(name)_OBJS))))
```

Make fails in the above line saying missing separator.

```
:68: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Comment: I do not know the answer to your question.  The double expansion you want is tricky.  However, I see the `$$` in your Makefile text.  If you are using GNU Make, have you investigated the `.SECONDEXPANSION` target?

Comment: I get `*** No rule to make target \`libLIB.a(OBJ.o)', needed by \`libLIB.a'.  Stop.`

Comment: Also, you should be able to use `$(LIBS:lib%.a=%)` which is shorter than the equivalent `patsubst` invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the GNUMake manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Archive-Members):

> To specify several members in the same archive, you can write all the
>   member names together between the parentheses. For example:
>
> ```
>  foolib(hack.o kludge.o)
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
>  foolib(hack.o) foolib(kludge.o)
> ```

However this doesn't seem to apply to prerequisites (GNUMake 3.8.2):

```
# This works:
     flib: foolib(hack.o) foolib(kludge.o)

# This doesn't:
     flib: foolib(hack.o kludge.o)
```

So we just need a small modification (using @Neil's shortcut and some careful handling of parentheses):

```
# Change this:
$(foreach name, $(LIBS:lib%.a=%), \
  $(eval lib$(name).a : lib$(name).a($$($(name)_OBJS))))


# to this:
lparen := (
rparen := )

$(foreach name, $(LIBS:lib%.a=%), \
  $(eval lib$(name).a : $($(name)_OBJS:%=lib$(name).a$(lparen)%$(rparen))))
```

Comment: There's a space just before $(eval. To avoid that I have the command in just a single line.